# Overpass API with nginx

Tags: nginx, openstreetmap, overpass-api

In:
    https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API/Installation
I can read:
    Setting up the Web API only for apache. Is it possible for Nginx?

I am trying it but I always find 405 Not Allowed if I ask remotely

## nginx.conf

```
 worker_processes  1;
events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include       mime.types;

    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    sendfile        on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    server {
        listen       8000;
    location /api/ {
        alias /mnt/data/openstreetmap/osm-3s_v0.7.4/cgi-bin/;
    }
    #
    location /cgi-bin/ {
                gzip off;
                root /mnt/data/openstreetmap/osm-3s_v0.7.4/;
                fastcgi_read_timeout 900;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/fcgiwrap.socket;
                include /opt/nginx/fastcgi_params;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        }

        location / {
            root   /mnt/data/openstreetmap/osm-3s_v0.7.4/html;
            index  index.html index.htm;
        }
    }

}
```

In localhost:

```
wget --output-document=test.xml http://localhost:8000/api/interpreter?data=%3Cprint%20mode=%22body%22/%3E
```

--2016-08-14 18:07:38--  http://localhost:8000/api/interpreter?data=%3Cprint%20mode=%22body%22/%3E
Petición HTTP enviada, esperando respuesta... 200 OK
Longitud: 1983984 (1,9M) [application/octet-stream]
Grabando a: “test.xml”

test.xml                              100%[======================================================================>]   1,89M  --.-KB/s    in 0,004s

2016-08-14 18:07:38 (488 MB/s) - “test.xml” guardado [1983984/19839

In browser (remote client):
    **405 Not Allowed**

No problem with access to index.html

Comment: cross-posted: https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/51390/overpass-api-dispatcher-daemon-running-for-nginx

Comment: In the comments on your link you can see that I made the inquiry and that's why I write here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

write this

```
rewrite ^/api/(.+)$ /cgi-bin/$1 last;
```

instead of

```
location /api/ {
    alias /mnt/data/openstreetmap/osm-3s_v0.7.4/cgi-bin/;
}
```